# Implementing a parametrized thread-safe lazy-init cache using ConcurrentHashMap (without volatile keyword)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, lazy-initialization

The single-check idiom can be used to implement a thread safe-lazy init with (compared to the double-check) the possible drawback of wasting some computation time by multiple concurrent inits. It is

**Single-check idiom**

```
private volatile FieldType field;
FieldType getField() {
  FieldType result = field;
  if (result == null) {
    field = result = computeFieldValue();
  }
  return result;
}
```

Here, we need the volatile `field` to avoid that a partially initialized object is passed to another thread, that is - the assignment (write) implicitly performs the necessary synchronization.

I would like to implement a *parametrized* lazy init cache, which is essentially represented by a `Map<Integer, Object>`, where each element is created using lazy init.

My question is: is it enough to use a `ConcurrentHashMap` to avoid the issue with partial initialization. That is, in that case the thread-safe implementation of a lazy-init cache using the single-check idiom can be given by

```
private final ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, ItemType> items = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, ItemType>();

ItemType getItem(Integer index) {
  ItemType result = items.get(index);
  if (result == null) {
    result = computeItemValue(index);
    items.put(index, result);
  }
  return result;
}
```

In other words: I assume that 'items.put(index, result)' performs the necessary synchronization (since it is a write). Note that the question might be twofold here: first I wonder if this works in the (a) current JVM implementation, second (more importantly) I wonder if this is guaranteed (given the documentation/contract) of `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Note: Here I assume that computeItemValue generates an immutable object and guarantees thread safety in the sense of the single-check idiom (that is, once object construction is completed, the object returned behaves identically for all threads). I assume this is item 71 in J. Bloch's book.

Comment: Neither of your suggestions is thread safe. Multiple threads can call the `computeFieldValue` and assign the value to the field/add it to the map. For `ConcurrentHashMap` use `putIfAbsent` or `computeIfAbsent`.

Comment: They are thread safe in the sense of the single-check idiom that computeFieldValue is constructing an immutable object which behaves the same, even if constructed multiple times... (please the the single check idiom in Bloch's book).

Comment: @ChristianFries A correct singleton pattern doesn't initialize the instance more than once.

Comment: @Kayaman: In that case I would need to use the double-check idiom. I do know this, but it comes with additional syncronization and performance-wise it might be better to go for the single-check idiom.

Answer (score 4):

In java 8, you can use the [computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) to avoid even the possibility of duplicate initialization:

```
private final ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, ItemType> items = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, ItemType>();

ItemType getItem(Integer index) {
  return items.computeIfAbsent(index, this::computeItemValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> is it enough to use a ConcurrentHashMap to avoid the issue with
>   partial initialization.

Yes, there is an explicit happens-before ordering for objects read from a CHM relative to being written.

So, you cover visibility, but haven't touched on atomicity.  There are two components on atomicity

- memoization
- put if not present

You aren't achieving either.  That is, for memoization, you can create more than one object (not actually lazy-init). And for the put if not present, the CHM can receive more than one value since you are not invoking `putIfAbsent`.

Based on your last update, if they are going to be the same object and are immutable, than you should be fine despite extra construction.

Comment: Thank you. What if we have the situation that we have two different immutable objects which behave indistinguishable (except that they might have two different addresses / id's)? (I will edit my question in that directions)

Comment: @ChristianFries What do you mean by id?  Like a sequence? In that case you are in trouble.  If you can create two objects `ItemType a = computeItemValue(index)` and `ItemType b = computeItemValue(index)` with the same `index` such that `a.equals(b)` is false.  This won't work.

Comment: If you are using Java 8 and can leverage `computeIfAbsent` as suggested by Brett Okken, than definitely, definitely do that.

Comment: By "id" I meant s.th. related to the memory address of the object - but the objects are considered equal in the sense of .equals.